# How can I prove the betweenness of the tree straight segments

Tags: plane-geometry

I come across an elementary geometry problem as following:
[image]

Assume that $\angle CAD=12°, \angle CBD=24°, \angle CAB=36°, \angle ABD=48°.$ Estimate that $\angle ACD=?$ And I tried so far: Construct along the straight segment $AC$ an equilateral triangle $\Delta ACG.$ And if I know that $CD$ is between $AC$ and $CG,$ then I can estimate that $\angle ACD=30°.$ But I was totally stuck---How can I prove that $CD$ is indeed between $AC$ and $CG?$

Comment: If $ACG$ is equilateral, how did you get $\angle ACG=30$?

Comment: @5xum: I can prove $\Delta CDG\cong \Delta CDA,$ provided my question above is solved. And then, it is easy to show the desired result.

Comment: But $\angle ACG$ is one angle of an equilateral triangle, so $\angle ACG=60$!

Comment: @5xum: Sorry, I have made a typo.